# Add Certificate as Signature to CustomBinding

Tags: c#, security, soap

how can we add the certificate as a signeture in the SOAP Security element?

I was trying with different security elements without any luck.

also, using soap 1.1 is requaire.
and the request contains a signature without encrypting the request itself.

CustomBinding code:

```
 private System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetCustomBinding()
    {

        var transpor = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            transpor.RequireClientCertificate = true;

        var TextMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            TextMessageEncoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;
       
         var security = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
            security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
    
        return new CustomBinding(security, TextMessageEncoding, transpor);
    }
```

the result I am looking for :

```html
<wsse:Security 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <ds:Signature Id="SIG-B96FBA82A6CC8DCE51163645483630171" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="a s" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#id-B96FBA82A6CC8DCE51163645483629970"><ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="a" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxx</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
            
                <ds:SignatureValue>Kj5PmmCMQcrtfHmfsj2I8dQthdMFl2RO0V64ATKNjLYMynPI8RwO0SAMcvOxpclgp9QI8uxwF4OJ
et0MhrwirQ4Qo2plwh2UbMh/xSqxYTW/N7ifeJ=</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-B96FBA82A6CC8DCE51163645483629968">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-B96FBA82A6CC8DCE51163645483629969">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        <ds:X509IssuerName></ds:X509IssuerName>
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509SerialNumber>
                    </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</wsse:Security>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by using CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement

```
private System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetCustomBinding()
    {

        var transpor = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            transpor.RequireClientCertificate = true;

        var TextMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        TextMessageEncoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;


        var version = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
        var security =  SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(version, true);

        return new CustomBinding(security, TextMessageEncoding, transpor);
    }
```